Is there a continuous, non-piecewise, w shaped function that has a point at $(0, 1)$ and an asymptote of $y = 1$?
Is there a continuous and non-piecewise function that is shaped like a w with a point at $ (0, 1)$ and approaches $y = 1$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$?
A w-shaped function can be defined as a symmetric polynomial of the 6th degree centered about the x-axis with 5 extrema. I want a function similar to this but instead of approaching $\infty$ as x increases or decreases, I want it to approach 1 without changing the behavior around the center of the graph.

Have you tried composing $\arctan$ on even polynomials?

@kindasorta Yes, I have tried it, but the $y$ value at $x = 0$ is always $0$ with $\arctan$, and I'm not sure how to get the asymptote to be the same as the value at $x = 0$ for $\arctan$.

Because your $w$ shape has $5$ critical points, you may consider some symmetric $w$ shaped degree 6 polynomial, all of whose critical points are: different, and land in $[-2/3,2/3]$, and compose this polynomial on $\arctan (x)$. This would have the correct shape. May need to tweak with the parameters a bit to get the precise $w$ shape you desire.

If $p(x)=x^4-2bx^2+c$, $$f(x)=e^{-p(x)}+1$$ gives arbitrarily steep troughs centred at $x=\pm b$ as $c$ approaches $-\infty$.

If we try to achieve this with a rational function r(x), we may write $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$. For a "w", we want $r(x)$ to have three local extrema, say at $x = -1, \; 0, \; 1$.
We want no discontinuities, so we may assume $r(x)$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbf{R}$, and hence by Fermat's theorem for extreme values, $$\frac{d}{dx}r(x) = 0, $$ at $x = -1, \; 0, \; 1$. By quotient rule, $$\frac{d}{dx}r(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{p(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}q(x)-\frac{d}{dx}p(x)\cdot q(x)}{q(x)^2},$$ So we require $$p(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}q(x)-\frac{d}{dx}p(x)\cdot q(x)=0$$ at $x = -1, \; 0, \; 1$.
Let $p(x) = s(x)+a$, and $q(x)=s(x)+b$, for some unknown polynomial $s(x)$ and constants $a, b$. Then $$p(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}q(x)-\frac{d}{dx}p(x)\cdot q(x)=(a-b)\frac{d}{dx}s(x), $$ If we let $s(x)=x^2(x-1)(x+1)=x^3-x$ have precisely the desired roots, and $a\neq b$, $a, b>\frac{1}{2}$ to avoid a zero denominator, we notice the function $$r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{x^3-x+a}{x^3-x+b}$$ has exactly the desired properties. It is defined on $\mathbf{R}$, has a 'w' shape by virtue of its three extrema, and has $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}r(x) = 1$ since $\deg p(x) = \deg q(x)$ and monic. Particularly, $a=1, b=3$ gives a nice example.

The function you propose is not continuous.

Fixed. Thank you.
